# Core Data: Why need the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my understanding, NSFetchedResultsController do the job of sync data from managed object context to a table view controller. What's the role of the delegate here? I read the apple documentation and don't get it. Please elaborate the issue concisely and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the brief answer is that the delegate methods allow you to update the table view as appropriate when an action has been taken on a managed object in the NSFetchedResultsController (NSFRC).

For example, if you delete an object that's in the NSFRC's results then it can update the table by removing the appropriate row.

So...

- In `controllerWillChangeContent:` it is a good idea to tell your table view that you're going to change it (so you should call `beginUpdates:` on it)
- `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType` is called when a managed object changes (added, removed, moved, etc). Update the table view as appropriate (e.g. by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` if a managed object was deleted)
- `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType` is similar to the above, but for table view sections.
- `controllerDidChangeContent` is called when the changes are complete. Finish up in this method also call `endUpdates:` on your table view

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Why not just put these methods in NSFetchedResultsConroller class? Why need a delegate?

Comment: It is an elegant way for the NSFRC to let the delegate know when any of the managed objects have changed so that you can perform an action upon this. Making them class or instance methods wouldn't work as this would assume you would always know when a managed object had changed. It's not the only way it could have been done. There are some thoughts here: http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/

Comment: If you want to use class or instance methods here then it sounds like you want to control the managed objects yourself. In this case you can choose not to use the NSFRC and this is perfectly valid. In my opinion, though, despite the initial hassle of setting it up I do find that it not only takes away some of the pain of managing the objects and table view yourself, but also adds additional useful behaviour.